# v4l2-ctl error in script

Tags: shell-script, v4l

I can use v4l2-ctl in command line like these:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c focus_auto=0
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c exposure_auto=0
```

But it has error when I run them as a script in a file. for example `script.sh` which contains these two lines and run it using `sh script.sh` or call it from c++ `system()` function:

```
VIDIOC_S_EXT_CTRLS: failed: Invalid argument
Error setting MPEG controls: Invalid argument
```

why this error occurs?

Comment: Which shell are you using on the command line, and which shell is `sh`?

Comment: It's bash. I tried also bash.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `v4l2-ctl` command, are you running it as root?

Try this `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c focus_auto=0
sudo /usr/bin/v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c exposure_auto=0
```

Change `/usr/bin` if `v4l2-ctl` is not there but in another directory location.

Comment: I tried also running in root. but got the same error. also mention that errors say that `v4l2-ctl` has been executed but arguments do not satisfy it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shall include some delays with `sleep` in between the v4l2-ctl commands:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c focus_auto=0
sleep 1
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c exposure_auto=0
```

This worked for me with a different scenario with v4l2-ctl in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know reason of you getting that error, but following line could work without error & looks more compact.

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -c focus_auto=0 -c exposure_auto=0
```

Also, Correct me if I'm wrong. Camera devices usually takes even numbers right? (like `/dev/video0, /dev/video2, /dev/video4 ...`) Are you 100% sure that `/dev/video1` is your device?